# How to use a docker image to generate static files to serve from nginx image?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I'm either missing something really obvious or I'm approaching this totally the wrong way, either way I could use some fresh insights.

I have the following docker images (simplified) that I link together using docker-compose:

- frontend (a Vue.js app)
- backend (Django app)
- nginx
- postgres

In development, I don't use nginx but instead the Vue.js app runs as a watcher with `yarn serve` and Django uses `manage.py runserver`.

What I would like to do for production (in CI/CD):

- build and push backend image
- build and push nginx image
- build the frontend image with `yarn build` command
- get the generated files in the nginx container (through a volume?)
- deploy the new images

The problem is: if I put `yarn build` as the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, the compilation happens when the container is *started*, and I want it to be done in the build step in CI/CD.
But if I put `RUN yarn build` in the image, what do I put as `CMD`? And how do I get the generated static files to nginx?

The solutions I could find use multistage builds for the frontend that have an nginx image as the last step, combining the two. But I need the nginx image to be independent of the frontend image, so that doesn't work for me.

I feel like this is a problem that has been solved by many, yet I cannot find an example. Suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a volume in your docker-compose.yml file and mount the same volume to both your frontend container (to a path where the built files are, like `dist` folder) and nginx container (to your web root path). This way both containers will have the access to same volume.

And also, keep your `yarn build` as RUN command.

EDIT:

Containers need to run a program or command in order to be classified as a container, and so they could be started, stopped etc. That is by design.

If you are not planning to serve from frontend container using a command, then you should either remove it as a service (since its not) from docker-compose.yml and add it as a build stage in your nginx dockerfile, or you could use some kind of command that will run indefinitely in your frontend container, for example `tail -f index.html`. The first solution is a better practice.

In your nginx dockerfile add frontend build dockerfile as a first build stage:

```
From: node as frontend-build
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn build

From:nginx
COPY --from=frontend-build /app/dist /usr/shared/nginx/html
...
CMD ["nginx"]
```

Comment: What would I then put as the `CMD`? I can use multilayer builds to basically have an image that _only_ contains the compiled assets (in a `dist` folder like you say) and mount a shared volume to that directory and nginx, but what would I start the container with? 
Also, I believe an empty volume is initialized with the data that was in the container directory, but how would I deploy a new version of the assets?

Comment: I'm thinking, perhaps I could start the container with a `cp` command that copies the dist folder to the shared volume, overwriting any previous version and the container will simply stop after the copy command.

Comment: If you are not serving anything from frontend container, it doesnt belong in the services section by design. You should only use services that actually run. So instead, use it as a multistage build. I will update my answer

Comment: Fair point, I guess running a container that doesn't do anything is silly. But as I mentioned in my question I don't want to tie in nginx with my frontend service, since it's also connecting to a backend service and I don't want to tangle the two. Perhaps I can find a way to keep the frontend image clean and standalone for dev and testing, and pull a built image into my nginx Dockerfile to copy out the assets, since nginx is tying frontend and backend together anyway. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: you can leave the frontend service as is, and just add the build stage to nginx’s Dockerfile. Also, if you are not using nginx in development, you could move it from docker-compose.yml to, let’s say, docker-compose.production.yml and then use docker-compose’s file chaining to start production environment like this: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up